# JavaScript - store a countdown time deadline for page reload

Tags: javascript, storage, countdown

So here I have created a countdown timer of 10 minutes to initiate upon the press of the 'START' button. I want to store this countdown so that when the user goes off the page and comes back to it the countdown will still be going. Note that I do NOT want the countdown to stop and then continue where it left off upon page reload, I would like it to continue to it's specified deadline. Any suggestions?

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>



    <a id="sendButton" class="button" onclick=" startClock();">START</a>

        <div id="sectionClock">

        <div id="clockdiv">
            <div>
                <span class="hours"></span>
                <div class="smalltext">Hours</div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <span class="minutes"></span>
                <div class="smalltext">Minutes</div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <span class="seconds"></span>
                <div class="smalltext">Seconds</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
    var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
    var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
    var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
    var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
    return {
        'total': t,
        'hours': hours,
        'minutes': minutes,
        'seconds': seconds
    };
}
var flag = 0;

function startClock() {


    /************ INITIALIZE CLOCK ************/
    function initializeClock(id, endtime) {

        // If countdown time is 0 then operate
        if(flag==0)
        {
            var clock = document.getElementById(id);
            var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
            var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
            var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

        flag=1; 
        }


        function updateClock() {
            var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);


            hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
            minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
            secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

            if (t.total <= 0) {
                clearInterval(timeinterval);
                flag=0;
            }
        }

        updateClock();
        var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
    }

    var timeInMinutes = 10;
    var currentTime = Date.parse(new Date());
    var deadline = new Date(currentTime + timeInMinutes*60*1000);
    initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);

    document.cookie = deadline

    var cookie = document.cookie;

    console.log(cookie);

}

function sendTrack(){
    (function() {

        var trackUrl = document.getElementById("url");    

    }());
}

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Instead of `var currentTime = Date.parse(new Date())` you should use `var currentTime = Date.now()` or `var currentTime = new Date().getTime()`.

Answer (score 1):

on the button click - set the time as you are doing and then store it into localStorage. This will store the start time of your countdown.

```
var designatedStart_time = //time that the button was clicked;
localStorage.setItem('startTime',designatedStart_time);
```

Then add a function that on page load (or document ready) that the current time is determined. This can be compared to the stored start time, the difference can then be calculated and the removed from the countdown timer. Then the countdown can start at the new time.  Note that the stored value will be a string so you will need to parse it to get the time as a number.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var startTime = localStorage.getItem('designatedStart_time');
var currentTime = //mechanism to get current time;
var remainingTime = startTime - currentTime;
//reset coundown to remainingTime
})
```

For example, if you set the 10 minutes at 10:00 and you are on the page for 1 minute and you leave the page, returning in two minute, the new coundown time would be from 7:00.

This way you do not have to store the length of time that a user is on the page or how long they have been away - it is simply the current time minus the designated start time.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/aeoril/n5we64p7/)

The key is to store an initial wall clock time in a "start time" variable only instead of calculating a "deadline" time up front, then store it in session storage in case you navigate away or reload the page:

```
var timeStamp = Date.now(), // Set timeStamp to current wall clock time in ms
    timeDelta;

    // if startTime not set, put current timeStamp in session storage
    // and set startTime to timeStamp
    startTime = startTime || getSetStartTime(timeStamp);
```

Then, whenever you update the displayed time (and check if the timer has finished counting down), make a time delta (elapsed time since stored start time) by subtracting the current wall clock time from the start time:

```
timeDelta = timeStamp - startTime;
```

Then, if the delta is greater than the maximum countdown time, just display zero time left, otherwise, display the countdown time as the total countdown time - time delta:

```
if (timeDelta > timerMaxMS) {
  // ... stuff
  timeElem.value = msToTimeStr(0); // display zero time left
  // ... stuff
  return; // return, ending calling of countdown routine
}
timeElem.value = msToTimeStr(timerMaxMS - timeDelta); // Display time left
requestID = window.requestAnimationFrame(updateTime); // call countdown routine via rAF at next repaint cycle
```

If there is a pause in the time since the last call of your update routine, it won't matter because you are grabbing the wall clock time each time it is called and calculating the time delta each time properly according to the wall clock time, even if many minutes have passed since the update logic has been called.

In my case, I am using [window.requestAnimationFrame()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) instead of setInterval().  Although it provides a time stamp argument, it is not wall clock time but time since start of navigation, so that time would be reset on a reload.  rAF updates on the natural paint cycle of the browser, so is the preferred method of updating dynamically changing UI elements on a regular basis.

In getSetStartTime(), I first try to get the start time from session storage.  If it is present, I convert it to an integer and return it.  If not, it is assumed I am not running the timer or displaying that the timer has finished, so I use the timeStamp argument to set it in session storage (after converting it to a string) then return the time stamp:

```
function getSetStartTime(timeStamp) {
  var startTimeStr = sessionStorage.getItem('startTime');

  if (!startTimeStr) {
    sessionStorage.setItem('startTime', String(timeStamp));
    return timeStamp;
  }
  return parseInt(startTimeStr, 10);
}
```

There is also a clearStartTime() that sets the startTime variable to null and removes the 'startTime' key/value pair from sessionStorage.

Logic uses the session storage to restart the countdown timer on page reload or navigation away and back if it contains a start time key/value pair.  If the timer is in the stopped state, and should show zeroes and a green background, etc., this logic will still work to reflect that on the first (and only) run of updateTime():

```
if (sessionStorage.getItem('startTime')) {
  startTime = null;
  labelElem.innerText = RUNNING_TEXT;
  requestID = window.requestAnimationFrame(updateTime);
}
```

JavaScript:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  var FINISHED_COLOR = '#0f0',
    DEFAULT_COLOR = '#fff',
    RUNNING_TEXT = 'Countdown Time Left:',
    STOPPED_TEXT = 'Countdown Finished!',
    MS_PER_SEC = 1000,
    MS_PER_MIN = MS_PER_SEC * 60,
    timerMaxMS = 2 * MS_PER_MIN,
    startTime,
    requestID = null;

  function getSetStartTime(timeStamp) {
    var startTimeStr = sessionStorage.getItem('startTime');

    if (!startTimeStr) {
      sessionStorage.setItem('startTime', String(timeStamp));
      return timeStamp;
    }
    return parseInt(startTimeStr, 10);
  }

  function clearStartTime() {
    startTime = null;
    sessionStorage.removeItem('startTime');
  }

  function pad(num, digits) {
    return String((num / Math.pow(10, digits)).toFixed(digits)).slice(-digits);
  }

  function msToTimeStr(timeInMS) {
    var secs = Math.floor(timeInMS / MS_PER_SEC) % 60,
      mins = Math.floor(timeInMS / MS_PER_MIN) % 60;

    return pad(mins, 2) + ':' + pad(secs, 2) + '.' + pad(timeInMS % 1000, 3);
  }

  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var startElem = document.getElementById('start'),
      clearElem = document.getElementById('clear'),
      timeElem = document.getElementById('time'),
      labelElem = document.getElementById('label'),
      idleText = labelElem.innerText;

    function updateTime() {
      var timeStamp = Date.now(),
        timeDelta;

      startTime = startTime || getSetStartTime(timeStamp);
      timeDelta = timeStamp - startTime;

      if (timeDelta > timerMaxMS) {
        labelElem.innerText = STOPPED_TEXT;
        timeElem.value = msToTimeStr(0);
        timeElem.style.background = FINISHED_COLOR;
        // clearStartTime();
        if (requestID) {
          window.cancelAnimationFrame(requestID);
          requestID = null;
        }
        return;
      }
      timeElem.value = msToTimeStr(timerMaxMS - timeDelta);
      requestID = window.requestAnimationFrame(updateTime);
    }

    clearElem.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      if (requestID) {
          window.cancelAnimationFrame(requestID);
          requestID = null;
        }
        labelElem.innerText = idleText;
        timeElem.value = '';
        timeElem.style.background = DEFAULT_COLOR;
                clearStartTime();
        return false;
    });

    startElem.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      clearStartTime();
      labelElem.innerText = RUNNING_TEXT;
      timeElem.style.background = DEFAULT_COLOR;
      requestID = window.requestAnimationFrame(updateTime);
      return false;
    }, false);

    if (sessionStorage.getItem('startTime')) {
      startTime = null;
      labelElem.innerText = RUNNING_TEXT;
      requestID = window.requestAnimationFrame(updateTime);
    }
  }, false)
}());
```

HTML:

```
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Timer</legend>
    <p>
      <button id="start">Start Timer</button>
      <button id="clear">Clear Timer</button>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="time" id='label'>Timer Not Running</label>
      <input type="text" name="time" id="time" readonly="true" />
    </p>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
label {
  padding-right: 10px;
  text-align: right;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
}

input {
  width: 75px;
  height: 20px;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 5px;
  font-family: "Courier New";
}
```